# Android webview select html element on touch

Tags: android, android-webview

I was using [Web Alert app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.webalert&hl=en_US&gl=US) and I've found something that they do, that I am trying to do as well but with no luck. Basically I'd like to get the HTML element that the user touched.

I was looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211426/getting-the-element-touched-by-user-from-webview) but I always get empty extra and UnknownType.

My best guess is that for them to do [this](https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/DGXHGOTrdYd8X6z0hPCghkkRW54jyKrSD9ahVyO3kDx9v_Oaz-QbHqUCH2ZqoYB9YQ=w2560-h1440-rw) it must not be a native app or is another component and not webview.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

After searching online I came across multiple links that gave me an alternative idea on how to achieve this, then was easily to find the solution.

Basically if I can inject my own JavaScript into a page, then I can call my code.

**1st step:**
[How to get the element clicked on a page using JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9012576/1845593)

**2nd step:**
How to inject my JavaScript code inside webview:

- [This showed me that would be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72783557/inject-javascript-in-android-webview-to-replace-already-existing-object)
- [Then found this complete tutorial](https://medium.com/@skywall/inject-js-into-androids-webview-8845fb5902b7)

Hope this helps others